# What is the use of @Self() resolution modifier in Angular?

Tags: angular

Angular docs say that Self is `Parameter decorator to be used on constructor parameters, which tells the DI framework to start dependency resolution from the local injector`.

If I have a component like this

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-foo',
  templateUrl: './foo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./foo.component.scss'],
  providers: [BarService],
})
export class FooComponent {
  constructor(public barService: BarService) {}
}
```

Though I provided `BarService` in root injector, `FooComponent` will inject its own instance of service because it's in the Components providers list. And it will work without `@Self()`.

Clearly, I'm missing something because I can't imagine in which scenarios `@Self()` can be used.

I've read numerous articles on resolution modifiers but still, it is not clear to me what are the use cases of `@Self()`

Answer (score 1):

`@Self()` means the component need to provide it's own instance.

When you have `@Self`, even if the root injector has a reference, an exception will be thrown is the component doesn't provide its own instance of the service.

This is to ensure that instance does not depend from the parents.